# How to preselect checkbox in showQuickPick in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am using quickpick to display list of items and allowing user to do multiselect. I am using quickpick like this.

```js
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('command', async () => {
  const list = await vscode.window.showQuickPick(filedsList, { ignoreFocusOut: true, canPickMany: true});
}));
```

I trying to make like if user previously selected some items in the quick pick and next time use opened this quick pick I want to preselect the previously selected values.
Is it feasible to do it in vscode extension development.

Comment: can you do it with the extended version of the QuickPick list

Comment: @ThejasJainMj  Do you need a fuller explanation of how to do this?

Comment: If u have any idea on this, @Mark please add here that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the object `vscode::QuickPickItem` has a property

**`picked`**

> Optional flag indicating if this item is picked initially.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options.  In **both** cases you'll have to make `QuickPickItems` out of your `AccurevOperations.cpkFieldsList` as you cannot just pass strings as the first argument and use the pre-selection capability.  It isn't difficult to do this, just loop through that `AccurevOperations.cpkFieldsList` array and create objects with the `QuickPickItem` properties you want, like:

```js
const arr = ["1", "2", "3"];

// const quickPickItems = arr.map(item => ( { label: item, picked: true } ) ); // but this would select them all

const quickPickItems = arr.map(item => {
  if (Number(item) % 2 != 0) return { label: item, picked: true };
  else return { label: item }
});
```

So you would use your logic to set the items you want pre-selected to have the `picked:true` object property.  Then

```js
const options = { canPickMany: true };
const qp = vscode.window.showQuickPick(quickPickItems, options);
```

should show a QuickPick with your selected items.

---

The other option is to use the `createQuickPick` method instead, because with that you can use its `selectedItems` property.  So starting with your array:

```js
const arr = ["1", "2", "3"];
const quickPickItems = arr.map(item => ( { label: item } ) ); // and whatever other properties each item needs, perhaps nothing other than label

const qp = vscode.window.createQuickPick();
qp.canSelectMany = true;
qp.items = quickPickItems;
qp.selectedItems = [quickPickItems[0], quickPickItems[2]]; // your logic here

qp.show();
```

You will have to create an array of objects to assign to the `selectedItems` property.  Perhaps by `filter`ing the `quickPickItems` array (from above) for the `label`s you want pre-selected:

```js
qp.selectedItems = quickPickItems.filter(item => {
  return item.label === "1" || item.label === "3";
});
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: Thank you so much  @Mark it worked with your way of implementation.